# MySQL: Insert into table based on aggregated data from another table, and update the other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, call them table A and table B. I want to insert multiple rows into table B, based on aggregated information from a grouped query from table A.

My problem is that I want to then find, for each row that I used in the grouped query (which queries table A), the ID of the row in table B that it was used to create, so I can link to it with a foreign key in table A.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I have searched for features in MySQL that would allow this, but I can't find any. I've tried to solve this for a few hours, but all my efforts ran into dead ends, which I don't think would be useful for anyone that could possibly answer my question.

Comment: The problem with hypothetical table names with a hypothetical number of columns that relies on a “given” aggregation that is neither testable nor described is that it will lead to hypothetical answers that are incomplete or just plain obtuse 

Comment: You don't think it would be useful for someone to help you fix what you wrote?

Comment: Hypothetical table names are completely equivalent to the real name. Knowing the table names has no effect. It does not matter which aggregation you use, be it avg, sum or any other, the solution would be the same. I'm not expecting the exact code to solve my problem.

Comment: There is no code to fix, I'm trying to solve this problem, and I haven't been successful in approaching a solution. I need to fundamentally solve the problem, not try to iterate a non-working, fundamentally wrong solution towards success.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you can use next approach

```
insert into tableB (id, value)
select id, sum(value) from tableA  group by id;
```

[MySQL fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=724c97ed96fcf73d80c0839c380e75f8&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)